# Ошибка no match for operator in std::operator

Tags: c++

```
struct student {

char surname[20];
char name[20];
char batya[20];
char birth[11];
       char mos[10];
      char osn[10];
       int rus[5];
       int fiz[5];
       int inf[5];
       int math[5];
       char fac[10];
       };

int main ()
{

    node *queue = NULL;
    student *s, q;
    char *n = "end";
    int C = 0, k;
    float m;
    cout << "Enter the \n\tlast name; \n\tfirst name;\n\tbatyaname; \n\tdate of birth; \n\tmode of study (full-time, part-time);"; 
    cout << "\n\tthe base income (benefit, budget, off budget, target); \n\n\tscores the exam in \n\t\t-mathematics"; 
    cout << "\n\t\t-Russian language \n\t\t-physics \n\t\t-informatics;"; 
    cout << "\n\tfaculty." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    char buf[20];
    int i=0;
     for (int i = 0; ; ++i)
     {
        // scanf("%s",buf);
        cin>>buf;
            if (strcmp (buf, n) == 0)
            break;
         s=new student;
         strcpy(s->surname,buf);
         cin>>s->name>>s->batya>>s->birth>>s->mos;
         cin>>s->osn;
         cin>>s->fiz>>s->rus>>s->inf>>s->math>>s->fac;
         queue = push (queue, s);
     }
```

Ошибка здесь

```
cin>>s->fiz>>s->rus>>s->inf>>s->math>>s->fac;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хм. Разобрался, тупая ошибка - "массив" intов